# How do I Save the password to a friend's router on my LG REALM Smartphone?

Tags: wi-fi

Each time I try to connect to this router it requires me to enter the (very long) password.

I do not have to do that when I use my own router; I get connectivity without entering a password each time.

What's going on?

Thanks. batpark

Comment: Connect using WPS, and save the connection. If you can't, then browse around your own router's settings. There should be some option related to remembering old connections, but it depends on the Android version and whether the manufacturer has replaced it with one of their own or not.

Answer (score 0):

Or also, as `rjt.rockx` said,

you can use the ***WPS recovery tools*** for connect to router directly.
some apps can do that for find the **WPS password** :

[**WPS Connect - Google Play**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ngb.wpsconnect&hl=en)

With this feature, you can easily connect to any Router if WPS have it.(without need to entering again the password)